# Plasma 5.8 from backports: can't type into authentication dialogues!

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I have this weird problem. I cannot type into the authentication dialogues. I mean those from kdesudo, or the one to open the wallet. The keyboard input just gets ignored. It works in any other window, so I can type the password into konsole, and then copy and paste it (using the mouse, ctrl+v won't work).

Anybody else has this happening??! It didn't happen before the upgrade.

Thanks

Comment: I had installed Ubuntu 17.04 with Unity 7. Then I installed Kubuntu with KDE Plasma 5.9.4. I had the same problem, plus I couldn't type with (hardware) keyboard, in any KDE find (search) bar (field), like in KDE Application Launcher (Start Menu). Keywords: Ubuntu KDE Plasma {can't, fail, inability} {type, typing} {hardware, natural} keyboard

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Workaround 1:

1. Go to Application Launcher (Start Menu) -> Applications -> Settings -> Set Keyboard Input Method. Then, a message will come up: 'Current configuration for the input method: ...'.
2. Select OK. Then, a new message will come up: 'Do you explicitly select the user configuration? ...'.
3. Select Yes. Then, a list will come up.
4. Select 'default' - 'use cjkv mode set by /etc/default/im-config'. Then, a new message will come up: 'Setting the user configuration /home/user/.xinputrc to xim. ...'.
5. Select OK.
6. Restart KDE session (log-out and then log-in to KDE).

Workaround 2:

1. Go to Application Launcher (Start Menu) -> Applications -> Settings -> Set IBus Preferences. Then, a message will come up: 'Keyboard Input Methods (IBus Daemon) is not running. Do you wish to start it?'
2. Select Yes. Then, a new message will come up: 'IBus has been started! ...'.
3. Select OK.

If workaround-2 works for you, then, you will have to repeat it, in every KDE session (after every log-in to KDE). So, workaround-2 is not permanent.

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy!

Comment: Thank you Yianni! Your first solution did not work, but the second one solved my issues, as well. Had the same problem after clean installing Debian 9. Solution 2 can be made permanent by adding **ibus-daemon** in the Autostart programs.

Comment: This is a lifesaver. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs in KDE NEON with KDE5.8.6(5), no matter whether clean install or not.

Symptoms are little wider, it is not possible to write letters into plasma dialogs (network widget etc.) and into alt+2 launcher.

Kickoff accepts only first letter, anything after it is being ignored.

Comment: So, I believe those are two different problems. The first one is typing into password boxes. This I believe was a problem of my particular  installation. The other one is typing into Kicker, or the Alt-F2 box. I am experiencing that behaviour too, and this is not related to the one I described here.

Comment: I have the same thing, the first letter is accepted, then if you keep pressing letters, eventually another will be accepted...

Comment: Also, for the next time: you should post your comments using the link "Add a comment", and not as an answer, unless you are really giving an answer to the question.

Comment: Um, yeah, can be, I experience both bugs then :) Ok guys, your feedback will be appreciated here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=376866

Comment: Great, I commented there. I un-accepted my own solution, because after further testing it does in fact not solve the problem, only makes it more random to me.